# Localizing integer values

Tags: c#, localization, globalization, cultureinfo

We have a WPF desktop application that I need to refactor to support non-UK cultures. Clearly, decimal values can cause issues, for example where the decimal point character can differ in different regions ("." in UK but "," in France).

What I'm less clear on is the impact on integer values. For example we might have code that concatenates an integer value to generate an "ID", e.g.

```
var id = $"A{MemberNo}".
```

If the value of `MemberNo` is 12345 then I want the resulting string to be "A12345".

By introducing cultures into the mix, I'm concerned that some might result in, say, "thousands" separators being added to the string, e.g. "A12,345" (although after some testing, I've yet to find a culture where this does happen).

So my question is: when specifically converting *integers* to strings, will it always result in "12345" regardless of culture, or should I refactor such code to use InvariantCulture, e.g.

```
string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "A{0}", MemberNo);
```

Comment: I would have to look for a source, now, but I am pretty confident that the default is to format ints as-is. If you _want_ separators, you need to opt-in. But don't take my word for it.

Comment: Does this provide enough info? [C# String interpolation Culture-specific formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#culture-specific-formatting)

Comment: @Silvermind I ran the example code and the thousands separators are added as a result of the N3 format. If I remove this then the number is displayed as "299792,458" in all three cases, regardless of culture (which is what I was hoping for).

Comment: "Is it necessary to localize this code?" Well clearly you shouldn't localise it, because you said you expect "the resulting ID string to be A12345". Instead of "localize this code", did you mean to ask "do I need to change this code so that it is culture-insensitive" instead?

Answer (score -1):

There is a website that .NET uses for CultureInfo: https://icu.unicode.org/

I have tried a new CultureInfor("hi-IN") as a parameter for checking if Convert.ToString() changed an int to a string with separators and didn't get any (the website mentioned that this culture has separators in numbers).

Probably .NET will not be adding any separators to ints but if you need you can check with the link

Comment: I changed my answer accordingly @Fildor